How can I tweak this additional Button CSS (reveal on hoover+Animation)
So I am looking for some advice on how I can further tweak the CSS code found in this thread. I have provided it below as well. This what I have on my site.
My site link:
The code:
I can't seem to add the code properly but it's visible on the stack overflow link above.
I would like it to perform more like this websites button reveal
and I would like it to happen on all pages like these (candles, rosaries, etc
except individual product pages like this https://matthewm288.sg-host.com/product/a-first-book-of-bible-stories-board-book-40454/
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
I tried the code mentioned above which does work but not exactly how I need it.

I have removed the code as I need to push the site live sooner rather than later but advice on this would still be greatly appreciated.
